# FFMPEG best quality image extraction possible

Tags: ffmpeg, encoder, image-extraction

I would like to extract pictures (png) out of a video for a 3D-modelling task. They should be in the best possible quality.
Video is : 1920x1080, 60 fps, 24 bit depth, mp4 .. I have now tried different approaches and feel like I should go with:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync vfr thumb%04d.png -hide_banner`
but I am not sure if I could get even a higher quality out. Zooming in will be really important.
Thanks for every help.

Answer (score 2):

PNG is lossless, so this is the best possible quality. Doesn't mean the color reproduction will necessarily be accurate.

Somewhat faster to run

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i input.mp4 -vsync vfr thumb%04d.png -hide_banner
```

Comment: so for dummies: does that mean that I don´t have to add any fancy add ons to the command to "improve" the quality of the extracted image because it will be the same all the time anyway? - not regarding color

Comment: Yes, PNG remains lossless.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure that the colour representation will be accurate?